# Jquery selector is empty which scope should I use

Tags: javascript, jquery, unobtrusive-javascript

I try to show and hide a div by the click of two different links. (Actually my page got a lot of these sections so I had to give them an ID).

my html looks like this

```
<div id="meta-503d22ceaf32609515000003" class="answer-form">
    <form action="..." method="...">
        <p>
            <textarea name=".."></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value=".."> 
            <a href="#" data-action="cancel" data-id="503526f7e8d08ecb0c000003">cancel</a>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
<span class="content-nav">
    <a href="#" data-action="open" data-id="503d22ceaf32609515000003">open form</a>
</span>
```

I have a `span` `content-navigation` when I click the link with `data-action=open` it opens the form. This works jus fine. But when I click cancle it should hide/close/slide up this answer form div.

Here is my jQuery-Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a[data-action=open]").on('click', function(e) {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        console.log($("div#meta-" + id));
        $("div#meta-" + id).slideDown('slow');
    });

    $("a[data-action=cancel]").on('click', function(e) {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        console.log(id);
        console.log(e);
        console.log($("#meta-" + id));
    });

});​
```

in the second bind click method it retrieves the id but the query

```
$("#meta-"+id)
```

does not find anything in the secound method while the same call finds something in the first method.

How can I find the form and close it? Is it a scope issue because the cancel call (binding) is nested inside the form?

What do I miss here?

Comment: "it should hide/close/slide up this answer form" why? I see no such actions in your cancel code.

Comment: Is there an object in your HTML with id="meta-503526f7e8d08ecb0c000003"?  I don't see one.  That's what the Cancel code is looking for and the cancel code doesn't actually do anything except `console.log()`.

Comment: `503526f7e8d08ecb0c000003 != 503d22ceaf32609515000003`

Comment: The `data-id` value of the `cancel` link is different than the ID of the `div`. `503526f7e8d08ecb0c000003` vs `503d22ceaf32609515000003`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.... looks like it was to late at night for me and I got a bug in my server side code that populate the id's. Thanks everyone for the head's up... I was nearly going crazy =)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, your Id for the cancel button looks different from the div Id